# Would you readily explain the usages of need?

Tags: british-english, auxiliary-verbs

Having studied several different grammar books, I am still confused as to whether these have the same meaning and can you use them interchangeably?

- Don't need to
- Don't have to
- Needn't

Would you tell me what is the difference between these and when you would rather use them? and what is the past tense of these?

- Tell her she needn't work tonight.
- Tell her she doesn't need to work tonight.

Do you consider this explanation correct?

- If we talk about a matter that is about general necessity, we must use don't need to do something
- If we don't talk about habitual and general society, then we must use needn't do something

Comment: Posible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116108/are-the-expressions-you-neednt-and-you-dont-need-to-different-in-meaning

Comment: Additional reference material (the duplicate does not address the 'need vs have' angle: http://mark.yates.net/engextra/n03/ch12/n3_ch12_neednt-havent-mustnt_jqz.htm

Comment: Is this correct?
NEEDN'T is the same as DON'T NEED TO

Comment: They have the same literal meaning.

Comment: @nima In meaning, yes. But *needn't* is now marginal in AmE, and it may eventually disappear from BrE as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Don't need to" and "needn't" have the same meaning here, if slightly different tones.

The real distinction is between "need to" and "have to":

To "need to" do something is to have a need for some activity. "I need to eat to live" - the process of living requires eating.

To "have to" is less specific. Perhaps "I have to eat because my mother is forcing me," but I don't necessarily "need to" for any reason - perhaps I have eaten sweets all day and am not hungry.

Unfortunately, in every day English usage these are often used interchangeably for anything that must be done for some reason. In this case, saying someone "needs to" do something is slightly more polite than saying they "have to." "Have to" can convey a sense that an external force is making you do something.